# openstack: liberty keystone installation unmet dependencies

Tags: python, ubuntu, openstack, keystone

I'm new to openstack and I'm trying to setup an all-In-One environment
I'm Working with Ubuntu 14.04 image

I'm following this guide:
http://fosskb.in/2015/10/20/openstack-liberty-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-ubuntu-15-10/

When installing keystone with the following command:

apt-get install -y keystone apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi memcached python-memcache python-openstackclient

It tells me the following packages have unmet dependences:

```
keystone : Depends: python-keystone (= 2:8.0.1-0ubuntu1~cloud0) but 1:2014.1.5-0ubuntu1 is to be installed

python-openstackclient: Depends: python-cinderclient (>= 1:1.3.1) but 1:1.0.8-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
Depends: python-glanceclient (>= 1:0.18.0) but 1:0.12.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: python-keystoneclient(>= 1:1.6.0) but 1:0.7.1-ubuntu1.3 is to be installed
Depends: python-neutronclient(>= 1:2.6.0) but it is not going to be installed 
Depends: python-novaclient(>= 2:2.28.1) but 1:2.17.0-0ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
Depends: python-oslo-serialization (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: python-oslo.utils (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

aptitude tells me that python-keystone has the following dependences that are unavailable or unsatisfied:

```
python-cryptography (>= 1.0) (unavailable)
python-keystoneclient (>= 1:1.6.0) (unsatisfied)
python-keystonemiddleware (>= 2.0.0) (unsatisfied)
python-migrate (>= 0.9.6) (unsatisfied)
python-msgpack(>=0.4.0) (unavailable)
python-oslo.concurrency (>= 2.3.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.config(>= 1:2.3.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.context(>= 0.2.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.db (>=2.4.1) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.i18n (>= 1.5.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.log (>= 1.8.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.messaging (>= 1.16.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.middalware (>= 2.8.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.policy(>= 0.5.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.serialization (>= 1.4.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.service (>= 0.7.0) (unsatisfied)
python-oslo.utils (= 2.0.0) (unsatisfied)
python-pycadf (>= 1.1.0) (unsatisfied)
python-pysaml2 (>= 2.4.0) (unsatisfied)
python-sqlalchemy (>= 1.0~) (unsatisfied)
```

How to fix these dependences?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the liberty repository added.
sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:liberty

If you get a command not found.
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

Comment: Hi twa16
Thanks for replying.
I did add the liberty repository. 
If you have any other ideas id be delighted to hear them.